# Problems updating to OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos

I am trying to update to OS X Yosemite. It is asking me for an iTunes Store password of a different email address and I can't change it. What should I do?

Comment: Presumably you mean trying to chnage the email address - how did you set it and what have you tried

Answer (score 3):

Open the App Store and on the main page, sign out of the currently logged in Apple ID. Sign in with your Apple ID and then try to click upgrade/install on the Yosemite page.